# Xcode 6 continuous integration can't find provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server

With Xcode 5 i was able to manually copy the profiles to where they needed to be. This is not the case with Xcode 6. I have added the server to the team and still cannot build. I can build fine from Xcode on the same machine. I get the following message:

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles containing one of the following signing identities was found:
```

It should work since Xcode works but Apple keeps hiding these settings more and more and I'm left without a way to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Have you tried to go to *Xcode->Preferences...->Accounts*, select your Apple ID (if there's more than one), double click the correct team and then hit the refresh button (lower left corner). This should download all profiles&signatures needed and place them where Xcode wants them. Also make sure that profile selection for the target is "automatic" and the correct team ID is selected in the target's general settings. Xcode has gotten really good picking the right profile/signature if you do it like that. Works almost like a charm, just let Xcode do all that work for you.

Comment: Yes. It turns out I manually needed to copy the profiles to a new directory in /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles. Now I'm getting an error because "codesign" can't access the new special keychain apple is using for server, I can't access it either. Xcode 6.1 has a fix but I need server 4.0... It seems I can hack it but not sure if that's worth it or I should wait.

Comment: Jay´s answer helped me! For some reason when I add Developer account in xcode server, all needed provisionprofiles isnt installed in correct catalog.  When I copied the certificate to  /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles it solved the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: You guys should post that as an answer so I can upvote you, Jay upvoted!

Comment: Posted as an answer Andrew

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I manually needed to copy the profiles to a new directory in /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles. Now I'm getting an error because "codesign" can't access the new special keychain apple is using for server, I can't access it either. Xcode 6.1 has a fix but I need server 4.0... It seems I can hack it but not sure if that's worth it or I should wait.